# Translation for "buksi" (Hungarian)

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

"buksi" in Hungarian is an affectionate form of "head" - usually it's applied to smaller people (typically kids) and creatures with cute features (for example, a puppy or a kitten). This word is in addition to "fej", which is the regular word for "head".

"buksi" can also be used as an adjective, in front of "fej" (but not other nouns).

I feel that "head" just misses a lot of the additional meaning of the Hungarian word and I'm looking for a word (or phrase) that more closely matches. The best I can come up with is "cute little round head" but it feels long and complicated.

Comment: [***Bonce**?*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bonce) [***Noddle***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/noddle) is a bit "dated".

Comment: [***Nut***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nut) is another word, although it has other [slang] meanings.

Comment: You might also like ***noggin***.

Comment: And *loaf of bread* [or just *loaf*] (BrE - Cockney rhyming slang)

Comment: @Jim _noggin_ may work.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you, I've never heard _bonce_ before.

Comment: Some of these may be BrE only. You need to check.

Comment: 'Napper' is another possibility. But I don't think any of these are often used with cute animals. Children, yes.

Comment: Are you looking for a noun or an adjective to put in front of "head"? None of what's been mentioned works for "____ head".

Comment: @Laurel Not necessarily - I'm trying to translate the word itself and I only brought it up as an adjective to give adequate detail about its usage.

Comment: There are lots of informal synonyms for *head*, but I don't think any of them are specific to heads that are cute or tiny.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not really familiar with most of them. I've heard noggin before but I don't think I knew any of the others so far. It's possible I know some more but I can't think of any right now.

Comment: @xxbbcc Have you tried looking in a thesaurus?

Comment: @Barmar No, I'm not looking for a list of synonyms but a particular word / phrase that captures the meaning of the original word.

Comment: So go through the list of synonyms, and see if any of them capture the meaning you're looking for. That's what I did, and none of them seem to fit, that's why I don't think the word exists.

Comment: I think this may be similar to the Yiddish word, "Keppie" which roughly translates to "little head".  Would you consider this related?

Comment: @Jim If you put "noggin" as an answer, I'll accept it. I think of all the variants, that's probably the closest.

Comment: @xxbbcc - Ok.  done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider [***noggin***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/noggin)  defined in Random House<sup>1</sup> as:

> 1. a small mug.
> 2. a small amount of liquor, usu. a gill.
> 3. Informal. a person's head.
>
> [1620–30; orig. uncertain]

The third definition is applicable here.

---

<sup>1 <sub>noggin. (n.d.) Random House Kernerman Webster’s College Dictionary. (2010). Retrieved July 28 2017</sub></sup>

Answer (score 2):

My parents, being from Ontario, Canada, would call such a child or pet 'Peanut'. Or, "Olivia is just a little peanut" - given the exagerated head and similiar appearance to a peanut viewed from above.

https://www.names.org/n/peanut/about

Also, there is a common term used for small children and late toddlers with enormous looking head, "Munchkin" which comes soleely from the race of small people in The Wizard of Oz by L. Frank Baum(1900) which is not a direct definition but if you said "Oh, that little munchkin?" and the subject was small with a large head, the meaning would come across clearly.

Answer (score 1):

From the Dictionary of American Slang:

[***coconut***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/coconut)

Comment: Just curious, is that where 'nut' comes from? (as per @Mick)

Answer (score -1):

you might be missing the point with the word "Buksi" and "buksi".

Of course it is used for small kids when you do care of them and would like to say very kindly as "take care of your head, small boy" or for a little baby you might says "you have a cute little head". In these cases, the Hungarian people can use "buksi" to emphasize the cuteness of small kid.

The "Buksi" with capital however, is a traditional Hungarian name for dogs (only). You might be able to find this dog name in older Hungarian books. Similar traditional dog names are "Morzsi", "Morzsa", etc. One of our famous poets, Sandor Petofi use "Morzsa" at one of his poems.

As a very popular dog name, we probably have thousands of dogs in Hungary with name "Buksi". I personaly very like to use this word either for a dog or just emphasize how cute is a little baby's face and head using "buksi" instead of the regular and boring "fej" which means "head".